# Remainder of Exponential Function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am asked by my teacher :
Find the Maclaurin series generated by $f(x)=e^{3x}$ and show that the series converges to the function $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My teacher also gave me a hint: Prove that $|M(x)-f(x)|$ approaches $0$ by using Sandwich Theorem, i.e. $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}0\leq|M(x)-f(x)|\leq\epsilon$, where $M(x)$ is the Maclaurin Series for $f(x)=e^{3x}$.

I found the Maclaurin series, but I could not find a function that I can use to use Sandwich Theorem. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps you could choose $n$ large enough so that $|{x \over 2}| < {1 \over 2}$, and replace the 'tail' of the sequence by something of the form $K {1 \over 2^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$\forall x\in\mathbb R  \;\forall n>0$

$$e^{3x}=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(3x)^k}{k!}+R(x,n,c)$$

with $c\in(0,3x)$ and

$$R(x,n,c)=\frac{(3x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}3^{n+1}e^{3c}$$

but $$0<|R(x,n,c)|<U(x,n)$$

with $$U(x,n)=\frac{(9|x|)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^{3|x|}$$

and by ratio test,

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{U(x,n+1)}{U(x,n)}=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}U(x,n)=0$$

qed.

Comment: why does the remainder depend on anything other than x and n?

Comment: If you use $n! > (n/e)^n$ you can get an explicit bound.